# Erro no Netbeans ao criar projeto

Tags: linux, netbeans

Meu erro é na IDE, estou utilizando **Debian Jessie**, decidi usar áhá pouco tempo. A instalação do Netbeans ocorreu perfeitamente, a instalação do JDK também porém ele me retorna este erro:

[image: Imagem para demonstrar o erro]

Tentei reinstalar porém não funcionou, removi o JDK e instalei novamente e mesmo assim me retorna o mesmo erro idêntico, alguém tem alguma idéia?

O erro acontece toda vez que tento criar um novo projeto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que acontece é que às vezes o Netbeans não encontra a pasta onde o JDK está instalado.

Para resolver isso, você deve adicionar a pasta manualmente no arquivo de configuração do Netbeans.

Siga os passos abaixo:

1. Abra o arquivo **netbeans.conf** localizado na pasta ***netbeans/etc*** com qualquer editor de texto.
2. Insira a localização da Instalação do JDK. No **Windows** é *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67* (ou algo deste tipo, dependendo da versão) e no **Linux** é */usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/* (ou algo deste tipo, dependendo da versão)
3. Salve o arquivo **netbeans.conf** e rode o executável que está na pasta ***netbeans/bin***

Comment: Agradeço pelo apoio, funcionou perfeitamente após eu incluir o caminho no arquivo netbeans.conf

Comment: Como eu passo esse caminho dentro do arquivo? É só incluir o caminho da  pasta?